# How do I get yyyy-mm format from 2 different columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, casting, concatenation

I have 1 column that displays year number in the format 1999 and I have another column that displays month number as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.

How do I get the single months to display with a 0 in front? I need to combine these 2 columns to display in the form of `yyyy/mm` so it will be `1999/01` for January 1999.

I tried:

```
SELECT
    YearNumber + '/' + FORMAT(MonthNumber, 'mm') AS PaymentMonth
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type smallint

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Column data type? (int/varchar/etc?)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
    CAST(YearNumber AS varchar(4)) + '/' + 
    LEFT('0' + CAST(MonthNumber AS varchar(2)), 2) AS PaymentMonth;
```

Comment: You are welcome, can you pls mark as this answer solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: `LEFT ('0' + '12', 2)` would result in `01`, wouldn't it???

Comment: `LEFT` needs to be `RIGHT`, then it would work ;-)

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that `+` is MS SQL specific, as DBMS in use is not mentioned in question – other ones use `||` for concatenation or `CONCAT` function – the latter one is specified in SQL standard, so should be the most portable variant.

Comment: @Aconcagua FYI, mssql also supports `||`, though your point is spot-on: most of these solutions are not completely supported across most/all SQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using `case when`:

The table:

```sql
select * from mytable
# YearNumber MonthNumber
#       1999           2
#       2000          11
```

```sql
select YearNumber || '/' ||
  (case when MonthNumber < 10 then '0' else '' end) ||
  MonthNumber as YearMonth
from mytable
# YearMonth
#   1999/02
#   2000/11
```

Note: the above works in sqlite, which tends to be more permissive with column types. In SQL Server, if the columns are not strings already then you may need to `cast(YearNumber as char(4))` or perhaps use the `concat` function:

```r
select
  concat(YearNumber, '/',
         (case when MonthNumber < 10 then '0' else '' end),
         MonthNumber) as YearMonth
from mytable
```

Other DBMSes have different dialects, they may differ slightly.

Answer (score -1):

**SQL Date Format with the FORMAT function**

1. Use the FORMAT function to format the date and time data types from a date column (date, datetime, datetime2, smalldatetime, datetimeoffset, etc. data type) in a table or a variable such as GETDATE()
2. To get DD/MM/YYYY use `SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy ') as date`
3. To get MM-DD-YY use `SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'MM-dd-yy') as date`.

Comment: I think this should work with most DBMSes if they have both the `FORMAT` and `getdate` functions, but those are not universal; perhaps you can include the DBMS(es) you think support this code. Further, the OP stated having two columns, `YearNumber` and `MonthNumber`, which seems not quite what this is addresses to work with.

Comment: Would fail, for instance, on postgre SQL...

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `concat()` function to join them. Depending on the database you can use `||` instead.

```
select concat(col1, '/', col2) from tbl;
```

This is also standard, but not enabled by default on MySQL, and possibly other databases.

```
select col1 || '/' || col2 from tbl;
```

Comment: Wouldn't expand single digit numbers to two digits.